# Spring XML bean configuration for mongo using connection string

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using mongo in my project and have configuration in applicationContext.xml file like :

```
<!-- MongoDb configurations -->
<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.database}" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

and using it like

```
@Inject
private MongoOperations mongoOperation;
```

But now I have moved mongo to secure server and it has username, password, host, options as replica set.

I can able to connect it using this syntax

```
String connectionString = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s%s", username, password, host, database, options);

MongoClientURI client_uri = new MongoClientURI(connectionString);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(client_uri);
        DB db = client.getDB(database);
```

Please advice how can i configure the same in config xml file or is there any config property by which we can set connection string.

Comment: Why not just put the uri directly into the XML configuration if you would rather use a URI? If all you want to do is build a URI from different parameter values in code, then I don't really see the point, as if they are already different parameter values then there really isn't any purpose in making a URI from them.

Comment: how can i put a direct uri in configuring mongo in spring xml file?

Comment: It's in the unit tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/resources/namespace/mongo-client-uri.xml

Comment: Thanks alot Neil :)